# Correct order of mulitple if statements in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I need this macro to hide certain columns when the value of $A$5 is equal to "Company 2".  The query below hides the columns successfully but doesn't executed the print loop.  What's the correct way to set this up?

```
Sub PrintAll()

  Dim BrokerCell As Range
  Dim TotalCell As Range
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim Wks As Worksheet

 Set Wks = Worksheets("PRINT PAGE")

 If Range("$A$5").Value = "Company 1" Then
  Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Names("Company1").RefersToRange
 ElseIf Range("$A$5").Value = "Company 2" Then
  Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Names("Company2").RefersToRange
 Else: Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Names("Company3").RefersToRange
 End If

If Range("$A$5").Value = "Company 2" Then
    Columns("M:O").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Else: Columns("M:O").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

        For Each BrokerCell In Rng
            If BrokerCell <> "" And Range("$S$5").Value <> "" Then
            Wks.Range("$B$5").Value = BrokerCell.Text
            Wks.PrintOut
            End If
        Next BrokerCell

 End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `For Each` loop is contained within the `Else` portion of the `If Range("$A$5").Value = "Company 2" Then` statement.  It will only execute when that `If` statement evaluates to false.

If you need your `For Each` loop to execute in all instances, then move it after the `End If`.  If you need it to execute only when the `If` statement evaluates to `True`, then move it before the `Else`.

Comment: I moved the 'End If' statement to before 'For Each' but it still only executes the hide or unhide column code - the 'For Each' loop still doesn't execute.

Comment: Your answer was the solution.  I'm guessing my macros got disabled at some point yesterday, cause we I opened and tried it out today it worked!  So thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what oyu are looking to accomplish, see below.

```
Sub PrintAll()

Dim BrokerCell As Range
Dim TotalCell As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Wks As Worksheet
Dim sCellValue As String

Set Wks = Worksheets("PRINT PAGE")
sCellValue = Replace(Range("$A$5").Value, " ", "")
    If sCellValue = "Company1" Then
        Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Names(sCellValue ).RefersToRange
    ElseIf sCellValue = "Company2" Then
        Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Names(sCellValue ).RefersToRange
    Else
        Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Names("Company3").RefersToRange
    End If

    Columns("M:O").Select
    If sCellValue = "Company2" Then
        Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Else
        Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If
    For Each BrokerCell In Rng
        If BrokerCell <> "" And Range("$S$5").Value <> "" Then
            Wks.Range("$B$5").Value = BrokerCell.Text
            Wks.PrintOut
        End If
    Next BrokerCell

End Sub
```

Comment: I like the change in the setup, however, it still doesn't solve the issue of the 'For Each' loop not executing.

Comment: if you debug the code, does Rng have cells? does it skip over the loop or go into the loop and hit the if statements?  If you change BrokerCell to a variant, remove the as Range, same issue? ( I assume so)  Now you should be able to reference BrokerCell and have its value represent the value held in the cell but have you tried BrokerCell.Value <> "".